# Как на PHP заменить " кавычки на « »

Tags: php, строки, замена

Есть строка, например:

```
Субстрат "Полесский"
```

нужно преобразовать кавычки в ней в такие:

```
Субстрат «Полесский»
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Решение зависит от кодовой таблицы - koi8r, cp1251 имют один байт на символ, utf8 - 2 байта. Во втором случае копайте в сторону "mb_stristr".

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [веб-сервиса "Типографа"](http://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/typograf/webservice/). Или ищите другие реализации того же, их больше одной, и есть в исходниках.

Comment: @bigov " <- это спец. символ, оно его не видит

Comment: не могу утверждать точно, на PHP писал больше двух лет назад, но мне кажется, что ему пофиг. Все должно экранироваться и конвертироваться. Технически это просто число (одно или двух байтовое). Давай исходники свои "в студию" - поковыряем.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если не нужна обработка случаев, когда внутри ковычек есть ещё ковычки то:

```
echo preg_replace( '/"([^"]*)"/', "«$1»", 'Субстрат "Полесский"' );
```

Comment: Прекрасно, идеально) Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Для вложенных кавычек:

```
function replaceQuotes($text) {
    return str_replace('"', '»', preg_replace('/((^|\s)"(\w))/um', '\2«\3', $text));
}
```

https://ideone.com/qlGPeu