# Замена кавычек на “елочки”

Tags: php

Нужно заменить в тексте кавычки на "елочки"; кавычками считаем как символ ', так и ". Есть такая функция:

```
echo preg_replace(['/(?:"([^>]*)")(?!>)/', '/(?:\'([^>]*)\')(?!>)/'], '«$1»', $text);
```

В принципе, работает, но заменяет только парные кавычки. Работает, кстати, тоже не всегда корректно. Нужно заменять независимо от того, есть ли в тексте парная кавычка - все нечетные на открывающую "елочку", а все четные - на закрывающую.

Для упрощения предположим, что в тексте могут встречаться только кавычки одного вида. Помогите решить задачу.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589358/Как-на-php-заменить-кавычки-на

Comment: А что насчет таких комбинаций, если могут встречаться кавычки разного типа? 
" "
" '
' "
' '

Comment: @MaKaRoN_IV, решение по ссылке поддерживает такой вариант, если доработать примерно так:

    return str_replace(['\'', '"'], '»', preg_replace(['/((^|\s)\'(\w))/um', '/((^|\s)"(\w))/um'], '\2«\3', $str));

Однако, странно другое: если писать кавычки без пробела, то будут ошибки - например, в таком тексте:

    Тек"ст

Поставится только закрывающая кавычка.

Comment: Ну и отлично, в любом случае это необходимо было учесть.

Comment: @MaKaRoN_IV, я дополнил комментарий, тогда не весь отправился.

Comment: Понял, распишите все возможные варианты расстановок и попробуйте тогда доработать Вашу регулярку к примеру здесь: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Также, вариант с одной кавычкой без текста обрабатывается неправильно: "Текст '" будет изменено на "Текст »".

Comment: @MaKaRoN_IV, https://regex101.com/r/0LgJkO/1